# elasticsearch upgrade from 0.9.x to 1.x.x

Tags: elasticsearch

Can i upgrade my elasticsearch just by moving the data folder from the elasticsearch-0.90.x folder to the elasticsearch-1.x.x folder, like this:

```
curl -XPOST 'http://localhost:9200/_shutdown'
ps ax | grep elasticsearch
kill 11243
mv elasticsearch-0.90.x/data elasticsearch-1.x.x
./elasticsearch-1.x.x/bin/elasticsearch
```

what's the best procedure to follow to upgrade from elasticsearch 0.9.x to 1.x.x ?

Answer (score 3):

The best procedure to follow is the one described [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/setup-upgrade.html#restart-upgrade) in the documentation, thats suits to your need, according to the table shown [here](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/1.3/setup-upgrade.html#setup-upgrade).

Moving the **data** directory could be sufficient if your cluster is very simple, but we don't have enough information about your current situation.

Comment: The links here no longer cover v0.9 unfortunately.

Comment: Actually I was incorrect, if you select v1.3 in the right hand version drop-down there is breaking changes information for v1.0

Comment: Thanks chris for noticing this : i've updated the links to point on 1.X documentation.

Answer (score 2):

It is best practice to always keep the `data` and `logs` folders outside ${ES_HOME} in a different directory which will make your upgrades easier (there is no need to move the `data` folder around). You can specify the paths in the `elasticsearch.yml` file.

```
path.data: /path/to/data

path.logs: /path/to/logs
```

When you're upgrading to 1.0 make sure you've covered all of the breaking changes:

http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/breaking-changes.html